# Purge mysql log bins older than two weeks automatically

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, binlog

I have to manually write

```
purge binary logs bin to "mysql-bin.somenumbers" ;
```

Once in a while, I need to reduce the spaces that binlogs are taking on my web server. Is it possible to purge binary logs bins automatically every two weeks? probably calling a bash script in crontab?

I have **MySQL 5.5** running on **CentOS 6.5**

Comment: I found myself an answer. We can use mysql variable expire_logs_days to remove the bin logs automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am glad [you found your own answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90521/purge-mysql-log-bins-older-than-two-weeks-automatically#comment162489_90521).

I am sure you found out you can add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
expire_logs_days = 14
```

You do not have to restart mysql. You login as `root@localhost` and run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 14;
```

To trigger the auto rotate immediately, run

```
mysql> FLUSH LOGS;
```

If you want to zap binary logs from the mysql console that is older that two weeks, use the [PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/purge-binary-logs.html) syntax. For example, here is a query to give you midnight two weeks ago from today's date:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
```

Just apply that query to [PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/purge-binary-logs.html)

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
```

Comment: Why the "+ INTERVAL 0 SECOND"?